# KeyError: None + argparse python 3.xx

Tags: python, yaml, argparse

```
main():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="IVS code")
parser.add_argument("--prod", help="Product to import config for")
parser.add_argument("--wf", help="File to write results to")
parser.add_argument("--ipf", help="IVS product family file") #not in use yet, might keep all ivs product family in same file
args=parser.parse_args()
print (args)

dataDF,keepDF,rulesDF,family_list,level_list,price_override_dict = getInputDataStructures(args)
```

=============================================================================

## function

```
def getInputDataStructures(args):

#Create the price override dictionary
    reader = csv.reader(open(cfg[args.prod]["po"], 'r'), skipinitialspace=True)
   #reader = csv.reader(open(cfg[args.prod]["po"], 'r'), skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    price_override_dict = {}
    for row in reader:
        cd,cntry,price = row
        price_override_dict[cd+'|'+cntry] = price
```

=======================================================================
YAML file ->
Sets and Miscelineous:

```
lvl: "ITEM_CODE,REGIONS,CLUSTERS,SUBCLUSTER,COUNTRY"
kl: Keep.csv
rs: rules.csv
pf: "Sets and Misc"
ps: "-"
pg: Product_Family.csv 
dt: "Sets_Misc.rpt"
po: "priceOverride.csv"
```

=============================================================================
ERROR OUTPUT:

```
24]: runfile('.../Workspace/CodeFiles/volume_substitution_v3.py', wdir='.../Workspace/CodeFiles')
Reloaded modules: config
Namespace(ipf=None, prod=None, wf=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-6b4c2ae644d5>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('.../Workspace/CodeFiles/volume_substitution_v3.py', wdir=.../CodeFiles')


  File ".../Workspace/CodeFiles/volume_substitution_v3.py", line 447, in <module>
    main()

  File ".../Workspace/CodeFiles/volume_substitution_v3.py", line 130, in main
    dataDF,keepDF,rulesDF,family_list,level_list,price_override_dict = getInputDataStructures(args)

  File ".../CodeFiles/volume_substitution_v3.py", line 21, in getInputDataStructures
    reader = csv.reader(open(cfg[args.prod]["po"], 'r'), skipinitialspace=True)

KeyError: None
```

How do I run it or what input should be provided to run this piece of code?
What could be a way to make this code working ?

Comment: How are you invoking this script?  From a shell?  The commandline will require something like `python yoursript.py --prod george`.

Comment: Agree with @hpaulj. KeyError: None looks like it's raised because it's trying to look up `cfg[args.prod]` but if args.prod is None, it would try to do `cfg[None]` which will raise that error.

Comment: If you don’t want to write code that can handle `prod`being `None`, you should change your `argparse` so that isn’t possible—either make it required instead of optional, or provide some useful default value.

Comment: @hpaulj I am trying to run ipython console of spyder, and running this way - yoursript.py --prod george gives me Syntax error, btw I am not sure of the input parameters aswell , i do not know what the code is expecting as input in place of george

Comment: @MatthewHorst I too see that its getting None as the value, but I was wondering if the input parameter for --> yoursript.py --prod "dont know what is the input" was from the YAML file ?

Comment: I don't see where `yaml` comes into this.  Do you understand the difference between running a scipt from an operating system shell (`bash` if on Linux) and invoking it from a running `ipython` session?  Or how to call a script with commandline values from `spyder`?  I've seen this sort of issue when people use `pycharm`.

Comment: @hpaulj if you see the line *** reader = csv.reader(open(cfg[args.prod]["po"], 'r'), skipinitialspace=True)*** , the 'po' value is pickedup from the yaml file
YAML piece :  po: "priceOverride.csv"

Regarding running the .py file from ipython console on spyder, does it make a huge difference when run on ipython and cmd ?

Comment: So your intention is that `cfg[args.prod]` will be the name of a `yaml` file?  In any case, as long as `args.prod` is the default `None`, this dictionary look up will produce a `key error` as opposed to a valid file name.

Comment: Your code has a `print(args)` line.  It should run before hitting this key error.  Pay attention to what it shows.  You might even want to test a stripped down version of this code, one that stops after this print.

Comment: Is your intention to open access cfg[args.prod] and the fallback be to access cfg["po"]? I.e. "po" is the default? If so you could do: `cfg.get(args.prod, "po")`

Comment: The NameSpace for the args variable shows this when i run the script: Namespace(ipf=None, prod=None, wf=None).
So basically can we figure out what could be the input parameters to be passed to run the .py file? or is it expecting something specific that can be figured out from the given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an editor I create this file:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="IVS code")
    parser.add_argument("--prod", help="Product to import config for")
    parser.add_argument("--wf", help="File to write results to")
    parser.add_argument("--ipf", help="IVS product family file") #not in use yet, might keep all ivs product family in same file
    args=parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args=main()
    print (args)
```

In a terminal window (linux bash) I do some sample runs:

Call the script without argument I get the default values:

```
1449:~/mypy$ python stack51971647.py 
Namespace(ipf=None, prod=None, wf=None)
```

With a `-h` I get the help:

```
1449:~/mypy$ python stack51971647.py -h
usage: stack51971647.py [-h] [--prod PROD] [--wf WF] [--ipf IPF]

IVS code

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --prod PROD  Product to import config for
  --wf WF      File to write results to
  --ipf IPF    IVS product family file
```

With various input values:

```
1449:~/mypy$ python stack51971647.py --prod foobar
Namespace(ipf=None, prod='foobar', wf=None)

1450:~/mypy$ python stack51971647.py --prod foobar --wf afile.py --ipf xxx
Namespace(ipf='xxx', prod='foobar', wf='afile.py')
```

From an Ipython session with the same working directory:

```
In [156]: run stack51971647
Namespace(ipf=None, prod=None, wf=None)
In [157]: run stack51971647 --prod foobar
Namespace(ipf=None, prod='foobar', wf=None)
```

I don't have spyder or pycharm so can't help with those variations.